# My reducer keeps on overwriting the value

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a reducer that concats a base price when you click on a menu item, then after when the user clicks on a modifier for that menu item its supposed to add a modifier object to the state but instead it just returns the mod_price object only. I am looking to have it return both the base_price and the mod_price, but instead it returns the mod_price object. Below is my code. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
/*This shows the cart price for only the selected item next to where it says add to cart*/
export const cartPriceForSelectedItem = (state = [],action) => {

    const {payload,type} = action;

    switch (type) {

        case SELECTED_PRICE :
           const {base_price} = payload;
            return  state.concat({base_price: base_price});

        case SET_MOD_PRICE_TOTAL :
            return  state.concat({mod_price: payload})
    }

    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If state is an object, you are looking for spread operator or `Object.assign` to return the new state with the merged properties.

```
return  {
    ...state,
    base_price: base_price
};
```

**Object.assign**

```
return  Object.assign({}, state, {
    base_price: base_price
});
```

One thing to note is that these operations perform a shallow merge, which I presume is not an issue in this context.

```js
const initialState = [];
const SELECTED_PRICE = 'SELECTED_PRICE';
const SET_MOD_PRICE_TOTAL = 'SET_MOD_PRICE_TOTAL';

const cartPriceForSelectedItem = (state = [], action) => {

  const {
    payload,
    type
  } = action;

  switch (type) {

    case SELECTED_PRICE:
      const {
        base_price
      } = payload;
      
      return state.concat({
        base_price: base_price
      });

    case SET_MOD_PRICE_TOTAL:
      return state.concat({
        mod_price: payload
      })
  }

  return state;
}


const action1 = {
  type: SELECTED_PRICE,
  payload: {
    "base_price": 20
  }
};
const state1 = cartPriceForSelectedItem(initialState, action1);

console.log('state1', state1);

const action2 = {
  type: SET_MOD_PRICE_TOTAL,
  payload: 45
};
const state2 = cartPriceForSelectedItem(state1, action2);

console.log('state2', state2);
```

Comment: Yep. Always copy your state object in redux so it's a new reference you're returning. Spread, object.assign, lodash clone or merge, etc.

Comment: Hi. I did that and i got an error that state.concat is not a function when it was time to set the mod_price

Comment: Ah. Looks like your state is an array and not an object.

Comment: Looking at the code it should be working as expected.  Can you provide the minimalistic structure of the state object ?

Comment: I am sorry. I still dont understand. I still keep getting an errorr message

Comment: How does your state look like ?

Comment: Sorry. I was looking at the redux dev tools and the "Diff" section and not the "State" section. It was working fine. Thanks a lot for your help